# A verb to say "treating several things the same way"

Tags: phrase-request

I look for a verb to say something like "to treat several things the same way"

Suppose following sentences I made with a fake verb "put difference"

> I put no difference between my children
>
> I put no difference between you and the other customers
>
> They put no difference between educated and ordinary people

Comment: *make no distinction*, *do not discriminate between*

Comment: There is always "*differenciate*"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasal verb "treat alike" would do well here.

- > I **treat** all my children **alike**.
- > I **treat** you and the other customers **alike**.
- > They **treat** educated and ordinary people **alike**.

In all these cases, note that the two words of the verb are split. That's fairly common in English.

Sometimes, you might be able to get away with "commingle", but that has more to do with dumping all together in the same bucket than treating identically: it's closely related, but not *quite* the same thing. Here, only the second sentence can really get away with it, and not very well; it's silly to talk about putting one's children all in the same house (who doesn't?), and almost as silly to talk about putting people in the same places regardless of education. But putting all one's customers in the same queue for the cash register or ticket counter is reasonable enough, and, crucially, so is putting them in *different* queues.

None of [commingle's synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/commingle) are at all useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "consistent"?

> **consistent**
>
> constantly adhering to the same principles, course, form, etc.

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Answer (score 0):

You ask about "threating the same way", yet you give negatives of "treating differently".

So, you need to look for an antonym to the verbs "discriminate", "differenciate", "individualize"...  I looked. There isn't any good one.  You will most likely need to use either the negative form "I don't ...", or use essentially the expression you started with, "I treat ... the same".